The isomorphism $\mathfrak{spin}(p,q) \cong \mathfrak{so}(p,q)$
The isomorphism $\mathfrak{spin}(p,q) \cong \mathfrak{so}(p,q)$, where $\mathfrak{spin}(p,q)$ corresponds to the second degree part of $Cl(p,q)$, is given by the map
$$ u v \mapsto [uv, \cdot] $$
Let's compute the matrix to which $e_i e_j \in \mathfrak{spin}(p,q)$ is mapped. To do so, let's apply it to a basis
$$ [e_i e_j, e_k] = e_i e_j e_k - e_k e_i e_j$$
We can split this into three cases:

$k \neq i, j \implies e_i e_j e_k - e_k e_i e_j = e_i e_j e_k - e_i e_j e_k = 0$
$k = i \implies e_i e_j e_i - e_i e_i e_j = - 2 e_i e_i e_j$
$k = j \implies e_i e_j e_j - e_j e_i e_j = 2 e_j e_j e_i$

Where $e_n e_n= \pm 1$. 
Denoting the dual basis with the upper index (no sum intended), we can write
$$ [e_i e_j, \cdot] = 2(e_j e_j e^j \otimes e_i - e_i e_i e^i \otimes e_j) $$
Now we want to see where an element $A^{i j} e_i e_j \in \mathfrak{spin}(p,q)$ is mapped. Using its skew-symmetry we get (sum intended)
$$ [A^{i j} e_i e_j, \cdot] = 4 A^{i j} \, e_j e_j \, e^j \otimes e_i $$
However, the text I'm reading omits the term $e_j e_j$, which has values $\pm 1$, and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Does your book write $e^j\otimes e_i$ or $e_j\otimes e_i$? The reciprocal basis (for an orthogonal basis) satisfies $e_j = e_je_je^j$ (no sum), so this would solve your problem. The reciprocal basis can be identified as the image of the dual basis under the musical isomorphism, if instead by $e^j$ you mean the dual basis.

@NicholasTodoroff thank you for your help. My text just states $A^{i j} \mapsto {A^i}_j$. I realized this may simply be a matter of lowering the j index with the metric (musical isomorphism), am I right?

I meant $A^{i j} \mapsto 4 {A^i}_j$, can't edit my comment tho

Yes, that would be the same idea in this case: $$4A^{ij}e_je_je^j\otimes e_i = 4A^i{}_je^j\otimes e_i.$$ It's important to note that this only works because $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ is an orthogonal basis.
